# why space is needed in this case '1 .__hash__()'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read [special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup)

In the example, it is:

```
>>> 1 .__hash__() == hash(1)
```

I understand in this context '1' is an instance of integer. I guess the space after '1' and before '.' to make the interpreter know that '1' is an instance, not something else, but I am not sure. so, I just want to have some confirmation. Could someone explain the reason of this required space after '1'?

Edit: just to clarify, I test this in interactive python prompt

Comment: Otherwise it'd be a float.

Comment: `1.__hash__()` is not a valid floating point number, which is what it's going to be parsed as due to the decimal point. I personally prefer writing it as `(1).__hash__` which I think is clearer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: in Interactive promt, `1 .__hash__()` returns `1`. No error. But, `1.__hash__()` returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @kindall: `1.__hash__()` is a valid float number followed by an invalid, unexpected token instead of the expected decimal digits or another valid token for the current top of the stack tracking an incomplete expression or statement.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: reading John Kugelman link, I now understanded what you are saying. Thanks both.

Comment: @andy: actually, John linked to a different page, I updated the duplicate link since. See the post edit history.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh, I see. The history shows the 2 links from you which explain directly on the issue while John links different page. Thanks for your links. It really helps clearing my head.

Comment: @anky_91: you comment about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311067/comparison-with-the-previous-line-and-summation/56311191#56311191, isn't it?  On that question, I groupby  'df.X1.ne(df.X1.shift()).cumsum()'. Not by `X1`. So, in case of `1,1,1,2,2,1,1`, 'df.X1.ne(df.X1.shift()).cumsum()' will separate first 3 of '1' and last 2 of '1' into 2 different groups. Thefore, the calculation is still correct.