# Comparison with the previous line and summation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is a table in dataframe:

```
X1  X2
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   2
2   2
1   2
```

It is necessary for each line calculate the value Y, where Y = X2(previous line)+1 if X1=X1(previous line), elso 0. Result:

```
X1  X2  Y
1   1   0
1   2   2
1   3   3
2   2   0
2   2   3
1   2   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
m = df['X1'].shift().eq(df['X1'])
df['Y'] = np.where(m, df['X2'].shift().add(1), 0).astype(int)
print (df)
   X1  X2  Y
0   1   1  0
1   1   2  2
2   1   3  3
3   2   2  0
4   2   2  3
5   1   2  0
```

**Details**:

First compare by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed valeus by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for equality:

```
m = df['X1'].shift().eq(df['X1'])
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: X1, dtype: bool
```

Then shift column `X2`, add `1`:

```
print (df['X2'].shift().add(1))
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
Name: X2, dtype: float64
```

And set new column by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print (np.where(m, df['X2'].shift().add(1), 0))
[0. 2. 3. 0. 3. 0.]
```

Another solution by @Divakar:

```
df['Y'] = df.X1.shift().eq(df.X1)*(df.X2+1).shift().fillna(0).astype(int)
#pandas 0.24+
#df['Y'] = df.X1.shift().eq(df.X1)*(df.X2+1).shift(fill_value=0)
print (df)
   X1  X2  Y
0   1   1  0
1   1   2  2
2   1   3  3
3   2   2  0
4   2   2  3
5   1   2  0
```

Comment: I ended up with - `df.X1.shift().eq(df.X1)*(df.X2+1).shift().fillna(0).astype(int)`.

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
c1=df.X1.ne(df.X1.shift()) #checks for changes in X1 column
```

Then we see wherever there is no change in `X1`, take previous row and add 1, else 0. Using [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['Y']=np.where(~c1,df.X2.shift()+1,0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

---

```
   X1  X2  Y
0   1   1  0
1   1   2  2
2   1   3  3
3   2   2  0
4   2   2  3
5   1   2  0
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `groupby` on groups of unchanged `X1`. On each group, doing  `shift` on `X2` to add 1 to it. Finally, `fillna` on changed values of `X1`

```
df['Y'] = df.groupby(df.X1.ne(df.X1.shift()).cumsum()).X2.shift().add(1).fillna(0)


Out[569]:
   X1  X2    Y
0   1   1  0.0
1   1   2  2.0
2   1   3  3.0
3   2   2  0.0
4   2   2  3.0
5   1   2  0.0
```